# how to provide secrets to an azure machine learning inference server

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

Within our azure machine learning inference server we want to be able to make calls to a password protected database.
What is the best way to provide a secret to the running inference server?

I have tried following this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-use-secrets-in-runs.
However the request to `run = Run.get_context()` always returns an offline instance.
Presumably that is only used for passing secrets to models when training them?

I was also thinking I could pass my secrets in as env variables but I'm not sure if that is safe?

```
env = Environment.from_pip_requirements(env_name, "requirements-azure.txt")
env.environment_variables.update({"mysecret": "password"})
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Here is [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-access-resources-from-endpoints-managed-identities?tabs=system-identity) to Access Azure resources from a managed online endpoint (preview) with a managed identity and  Azure Machine Learning inference HTTP [server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-inference-server-http).

Currently the following feature is in the roadmap to Provide deployed web service some kind of easy access path to the associated Key Vault, similar to how an experimental run of a model can use Run.get_context().get_secret().

Comment: what is the timeline for the run.get_context().get_secret() fix?

Comment: We aren't using "managed online endpoint (preview)". We are deploying it at as a webservice. How can I handle it in this case?

Comment: 1. Is what I suggested doing a security issue? AFAICS, the only place where these secrets are visible is in k8s deployments YAML files and you need access to the k8s namespace to read those.
2. If what we're doing is a security issue, can we do better?